# OMPL: Gets more points within the trajectory

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, ompl-planning, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!!!
I need some help with OMPL.

when the planner computes a path gives me a few points, and I need 200 Hz (500 points per second)

Anyone know of any parameter to change?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27801/ompl:-gets-more-points-within-the-trajectory/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The code that generates the number of points along the path is in ompl_ros_interface/src/planners/ompl_ros_joint_planner.cpp and ompl_ros_interface/src/planners/ompl_ros_rpy_task_space_planner.cpp; Each of these files contains a getSolutionPath() method, where you will see path.interpolate() being called.
By default, interpolate() will generate points on the path at the resolution that was used for collision checking. However, you can specify the number of points as an argument.
So you need to change the code to something like
path.interpolate(value);
This has no notion of time however, and it depends on your trajectory filtering how long the path takes to execute.

Another thing you can do (not recommended) is to make the collision checking resolution be much smaller, so you get more points. That will however slow down planning significantly. Changing the collision checking resolution can be done by modifying the value of the longest_valid_sement_fraction parameter in the loaded ompl_planning.yaml;

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2012-02-27**:
Thanks isucan!!